# How to fix Override method GetTitle in UIPickerViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I must populate the UIPickerView with some names, i can't see the names in the picker when i run simulations.

it seems like the getTitle overrige method is not used at all. i don't know why. i m getting nothing in the viewpicker

here is my model class

```
 public class MotifPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
     {
        //Attributes
         List<String> names = new List<string>();

    //constructors
    public MotifPickerModel()
    {
        names.Add("name1");
        names.Add("name2");
        names.Add("name3");
        names.Add("name4");
    }
    public MotifPickerModel(List<String> Names)
    {
        this.names = Names;
    }
    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return names.Count;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {

        return names[(int)row].ToString();
    }

    public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return 220f;
        else
            return 30f;
    }

}
```

here is where i instatiate the uipicker and call the model
i use a text input to call the uipickerview on the screen. and the tapgesture recognizer allows me to make it disappear when i tap anywhere else on the screen.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        var pickerMotif = new UIPickerView();
        //Here we must populate the picker
        var pickermodel = new MotifPickerModel();
        pickerMotif.Model = pickermodel;

        txtMotif.InputView = pickerMotif;

        var tapGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(Tap);
        tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer);

    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue locally with the code you provided.

Comment: you don't have any issue att all?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem. i found a link that helped me. 
here it is: 
[How to use PickerView as Combobox](http://www.gooorack.com/2013/07/18/xamarin-uipickerview-as-a-combobox/)